# How can I use regex to find data between quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract data which is between the single quotes.

```
"request='fgj234fgj9da41c76a8bc7d470kjykl89a5d'>"
```

I did try:
`^"request="'*'` but doesn;t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need the data BETWEEN the single quates, use look-behind and look-ahead in the matched pattern:

```
(?<=').*(?=')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex `'(.*)'` should do the work:

```js
text = "\"request='fgj234fgj9da41c76a8bc7d470kjykl89a5d'>\""
console.log(text.match(/'(.*)'/)[1])
```

Also you can use regex testers to see what your regex will find. I use [regex101](https://regex101.com/).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
const x="request='fgj234fgj9da41c76a8bc7d470kjykl89a5d'>"
const y=x.match(/'(.)+'/g)
alert(y)
</script>
```

This is going to return all those strings between quotes(' '). 
`(.)+` indicates at least one character should be there between quotes(' ')
`/...../g` here g indicates search throughout the string

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
^"request='([^']*)'>"$
```

1. `^` Matches the start of the string.
2. `"request='` Matches `"request='`.
3. `([^']*)` Capture group 1: Matches 0 or more characters that are not a `'`.
4. `'>"` Matches `'>"`.
5. `$` Matches the end of the string.

```js
let text = "\"request='fgj234fgj9da41c76a8bc7d470kjykl89a5d'>\"";
let matches = text.match(/^"request='([^']*)'>"$/);
console.log(matches[1]);
```